# How to abort apicall from reactjs/redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I just started looking at react&redux designing states+ actions. At the moment I  am focussing on api-calls . I created an apimanager and this is my request:

```
 axios.get('http://localhost:3000/0')
        .then(response => {
            store.dispatch(getDataSuccess(response.data));
            return response;
        }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
        store.dispatch(getDataError(error));
        return error;
    });
```

At the moment I am catching an error for a 404 but not for a timeout. How can I catch a timeout in react js/redux/axios?

Comment: Doesn't axios give you a way to handle timeout errors? Once you've caught the timeout error (I'm guessing the second argument of the ``.then()``) then you can dispatch your timeout_handle action.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should also reject the promise. Make sure the request is not pending, a timeout depending on the browser it could take up to 5 minutes (In chrome dev tools take a look inside the network tab).

Axios rejects the request promise with a "Network" error ([Source Code](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/4882ce5359c0ea5238de1cda21fb40a0584f9858/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L87))